# com.robotium.solo.Solo#clickOnView vs android.view.View#performClick

Tags: android, testing, robotium, android-instrumentation

In instrumentation tests,  should I use `com.robotium.solo.Solo#clickOnView` or `android.view.View#performClick`?

Both of those functions require View object.
Checking javadoc and source code, functionality  is similar.

But implementation is quite diffrent

- `android.view.View#performClick` calls `sendAccessibilityEvent` then registered event listener.
- `com.robotium.solo.Solo#clickOnView(android.view.View)` simulates actual finger click, on given screen coordinates (sends MotionEvent).

Are there any circumstances when should I use robotium function? It looks like it is just a lot of slower and more fragile way of having exactly same end result like `android.view.View#performClick`.